# Objective-C: C struct in @property with custom deallocation function

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, memory-management, struct

I have a C struct with custom allocation/deallocation functions because the struct has a dynamically-allocated nested array:

```
struct Cell {
    int data, moreData;
};

struct Grid {
    int nrows, ncols;
    struct Cell* array;
};

struct Grid* AllocGrid (int nrows, int ncols) {
    struct Grid* ptr = (struct Grid*) malloc (...);
    // ...
    ptr->array = (struct Cell*) malloc (...);
    return ptr;
}

void FreeGrid (struct Grid* ptr) {
    free (ptr->array);
    free (ptr);
}
```

I want to use this struct in the `UIViewController` of my Objective-C app. The grid's lifespan should be the same as the controller's one.

If it were a C++ object, I would call `AllocGrid()` in the constructor and match it with a call to `FreeGrid()` in the destructor. So I tried to put the allocation in the `init` message and the deallocation in `dealloc`:

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    struct Grid* theGrid;
}
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"init()");
        theGrid = AllocGrid(10,10);
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc()");
    DeallocGrid(theGrid);
    theGrid = NULL;
}
@end
```

But the allocation is never executed and I cannot see the "dealloc" log message when running the app in the iOS simulator. I guess I could do the allocation in `viewDidLoad` but I feel it's not the right thing to do. Hence my question:

**Question**: How can I wrap the C struct in a `@property` and force it to use my custom `AllocGrid()` and `DeallocGrid()` functions?
Or: Is there an equivalent of a `scoped_ptr` in Objective-C? Or should I roll out my own?

Comment: `-init` is not the designated initializer for `UIViewController`: [iPhone UIViewController init method not being called](http://stackoverflow.com/q/772182)

Answer (score 2):

I think putting the allocation in the `viewDidLoad()` is correct. In fact, there is a discussion regarding to why `init()` is not being called in ViewController, [iPhone UIViewController init method not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772182/iphone-uiviewcontroller-init-method-not-being-called). But, it depends on your context, if you want to initialize your structure "before" the view appear, you should put your initialization in `viewWillAppear`. There's another interesting thread talking about the invoking order in ViewController, [Order of UIViewController initialization and loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053498/order-of-uiviewcontroller-initialization-and-loading). Finally, I want to point out Objective-C is an extension of C, so the "basic" allocation/free behavior should be the same.