# Is there a difference between starting the app from Xcode and starting from the device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a few buttons on my View and when the app starts they should flip around their x-axis. When I start the app from Xcode (Build and then run the current scheme) they flip, but when I open the app on my iPhone they don't flip.

My viewDidLoad in my ViewController looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    model =[[Model alloc] init];
    GameView *gameView = [[GameView alloc] initWithTiles];
    gameView.controller = self;
    self.view = gameView;

    [self flipButtons];
}
```

Why don't the buttons flip when I start the app from my phone?

If you need additional information just let me know :)

**Edit**

This is the method that flips the button and gets called for each button:

```
- (void)flip:(Color*)color {

int flipDirection = arc4random() % 2;
if(flipDirection == 0) flipDirection = -1;

double duration = 200 + arc4random() % (500 - 200);
duration = duration / 1000;


// Animation
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, flipDirection, 0);
                     // wait duration /2 and call changeColor
                     dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)((duration / 2) * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                         [self changeColor:color];
                     });
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 0, 0);
                 }];
```

}

Comment: You telling that your buttons flipping in simulator, but not in device?

Comment: @Kathiravan No they're flipping on my device but only if I start the app from Xcode.

Comment: Have NSlog on your flipbuttons method. Start your application in device and check the device console in Xcode, check whether your method called or not.

Comment: `dispatch_after` should be in the completion block.

Comment: @TamásZahola May I ask why?

Comment: @Dalibor Yes. `UIView animateWithDuration...` provides no guarantee when or how many times will it call it's `animations:` block. However the `completion:` block is guaranteed to be called exactly once, after the animation has finished.

Comment: @Dalibor please take a look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948167/uiview-animatewithduration-doesnt-animate-cornerradius-variation
It says you shouldn't use `UIView animateWithDuration` with the `layer`s properties. In that case you should use CoreAnimation directly.

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLoad` doesn't necessarily mean that the view is on-screen. You should be using `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    model =[[Model alloc] init];
    GameView *gameView = [[GameView alloc] initWithTiles];
    gameView.controller = self;
    self.view = gameView;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self flipButtons];
}
```

`viewDidLoad` only signifies that the view controller's view has been instantiated and by that point all `IBOutlet`s have been wired up. You should only do additional initialization here, and must not rely on when `viewDidLoad` was called or whether it was called multiple times, etc (e.g. you can unload your view controller's view with `self.view = nil` if it doesn't have a `superview`, and it'll be automatically reloaded when it's needed).

Why this is necessary:
`UIViewController` loads it's `view` lazily. When you instantiate a `UIViewController` with e.g `initWithNibName:bundle:` it won't load the nib right away; that would be a waste of resources. According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:):

> The nib file you specify is not loaded right away. It is loaded the
>   first time the view controller's view is accessed. If you want to
>   perform additional initialization after the nib file is loaded,
>   override the viewDidLoad method and perform your tasks there.

So what happens is, when the view controller's `view` is queried the first time, loading takes place (see: [Order of UIViewController initialization and loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053498/order-of-uiviewcontroller-initialization-and-loading) ) and the `viewDidLoad` call is issued so that you can make adjustments to the view with all the subviews and `IBOutlets` set up.

Once the view is loaded, the view controller's state transitions are described in this diagram:

[image]

The initial state is `disappeared`.

Comment: Then please provide us with the implementation of your `flipButtons` method.

Comment: I'm sorry to annoy you but I still don't really know what to do now?

Comment: I found out that it runs the flip method because it changes the button color but somehow doesn't do the animation.

Comment: @Dalibor The button color surely won't be animated, because it's not set in the animation block. You're only _scheduling_ the color changing block in the animation block. You should do that as a separate animation with `duration/2` delay.